# It is possible hide a accordionTab with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

I am trying to hide a accordion Tab when visible variable be equal to `false`. Would it be something like this?

```
const visible = this.checkVisibility();
if (visible) {
  return <AccordionTab key={indexField}>
    IT SEE
  </AccordionTab>;
}
return (<AccordionTab key={indexField}>
  IT DON'T SEE
</AccordionTab>);
```

I don't know if any property is necessary, because I tried the following and it does not work.

```
render() {
  const visible = this.checkVisibility();
  return <div> {visible ? <AccordionTab key={indexField}> IT SEE </AccordionTab> : ''} </div>;
}
```

Show this error message -> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'headerClassName' of undefined**

> For some reason, it shows an error when rendering an empty
>   accordionTab or is hidden

Any idea? Thanks for you help!

Comment: I think the simplest way is to add a class to show, and a class to hide, with display:none or display:block, and set the corresponding class depending on state

Comment: Yes, I thought something like this <AccordionTab style="display:none;" key={templateField.displayName + indexField}></AccordionTab>, but this, does not hide the AccordionTab

Comment: Yes, the function returns the correct value in any case. The problem is the AccordionTab that gives an error when I try to hide it. I update my question with the specific error message.

Comment: Can you post your complete component code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ass long as your variable is a boolean you should be able to do this in your jsx :

```
render() {
  const isVisible = true;
  return (
   <div>
    { isVisible && <YourComponent/> }
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but not work. I think It is similar to my example and I get the same error. The error is: TypeError: instance.render is not a function -> AccordionTab(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`.

Any idea?

Comment: Oh ok i see, you forgot the render keyword, i updated my answere

Comment: It is not the solution either, I update my question adding with the code and the message of error too